# apt - install old versions of databases, e.g. mysql

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql, postgresql, versions

I am working on ubuntu 20.04 and I need mysql in version 5.6 or postgresql version 9.6.

I Know that I can specify a version using:

```
apt-get install mysql-server=<version>
```

And I can see the provided packages using:

```
apt-cache showpkg mysql-server
```

But how can I install mysql-server in version 5.6 if it is not listed?

Thanks Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu snapshots a specific version of PostgreSQL that is then supported throughout the lifetime of that Ubuntu version.

Other versions of PostgreSQL are available through the PostgreSQL apt repository.

This repository will integrate with your normal systems and patch management, and provide automatic updates for all supported versions of PostgreSQL throughout the support lifetime of PostgreSQL.

To use the apt repository, follow these steps:

Create the file repository configuration:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

Import the repository signing key:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Update the package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the latest version of PostgreSQL, if you want a specific version, use 'postgresql-12' or similar instead of 'postgresql':

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
```

My-sql aside from being owned by Oracle, it does not have those facilities, it should use Debian packages and there is no guarantee that it will work, plus it could break your system.

Also, if you want to try, here is a guide:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382968/install-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-20-04